# could not resolve hostname with scp

Tags: scp

I am accessing an ubuntu server over ssh with putty on my windows machine and trying to download a single file to my local windows machine

my windows username is Mark and my hostname per cmd is Marks I am trying the following command on the remote server

```
scp backup.sql mark@marks:desktop
```

and I get could not resolve hostname I have tried to put in what I think myip address is and the connection times out

Comment: this is not clear - your source file should come first and that will need the hostname or IP address of your ubuntu server included

Comment: even though I am giving the command from the server?

Comment: If you are on the server then yes, but your question states that you are accessing it using putty from a windows machine. I think you should edit this question to clarify exactly what you are doing and what you want

Comment: I thought issuing the command through ssh was the same as issuing it on the server obviously I am mistaken.  The first line of my question is exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: thanks for the help i will try and include the hostname or ip of the server with the command

Comment: It should go `scp user@host:/sourcefile destination_file` if you are on windows copying from a linux server the server user and IP/hostname will be needed in the source file

Comment: With SCP "from" always comes before "to" relative to where you're issuing the command. I think of an envelop (reading left-right, top-down) as kind of a mnemonic to help me remember.

Comment: You are right, executing the command through ssh is the same as if you executed the command on the server itself.  This command will try to copy the file backup.sql to a server named marks via username mark to a file called desktop.  The problem is that your server cannot resolve another machine on the network by the name of marks.  If you simply need to copy a file from the server to your windows client, WinSCP might be a better choice.

Comment: I had a similar problem but [the solution was](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148934/209677) to add the `./`before filename.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

binarysubstrate is right about the syntax.  The problem is, if the OP puts the name (or address) of his windows client in the 'to' part of the `scp` command, it probably won't work for a number of reasons:

1. his windows machine may not have a resolvable FQDN,
2. his windows machine may be behind a NAT firewall that is not setup to port-forward SSH requests,
3. he probably does not have an SSH daemon running on his windows machine.

To simply copy a file from the remote server down to a windows client, I would recommend [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php).

Comment: You wouldn't use your home machine as the destination parameter for the reasons you specified. Simply specify the remote server as the "from" parameter: scp my_id@remote_server:/orig_file /new_file

Comment: binarysubstitute, he mentioned that he is doing this from a windows machine.  Aside from Cygwin, I don't know of a command line version of scp for windows.  Is there one that you know of, other than Cygwin?

Comment: Yes, there is actually a [SCP PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) client. Though I have to say I much prefer Cygwin, which is surprisingly good all around.

Answer (score 9):

The syntax is this, relative to where you're issuing the command:

`scp user@host_from:location/file user@host_to:location/file`

And of course if you're local you can omit the user@host prefixes:

`scp local_file me@host_to:~/local_file`

The direction is always **from** > **to** relative to where you issue the command.

Comment: ok so does being connected to the server via ssh mean I am local and therefore can use the second syntax?

Comment: If you're transferring something from a server to your local machine, you often won't be able to "push" the file to yourself, for example if you're connecting over the Internet and don't have inbound connections set up. So instead, you just "pull" the file. So from my local machine at home for example, connecting to a server on the Internet, from my home machine I'd use scp myid@remote_server:/original_file ~/new_file

Comment: Thank you for the syntax I am sure it was right but the connection just kept timing out so I downloaded winscp as advised above and it worked immediately

Comment: winscp is just a GUI for this stuff so there was probably a typo somewhere. That's to say that if winscp works, then SCP from the command line would work.

Answer (score 0):

From the ser you ping your machine name ? Try replace machine name for the IP Address, or add your machine name to hosts configuration file from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same issu,
what i did is move one step back and run the command again

so if the command is like this

scp the_file me@host_to:~/

i changed to the back directory

cd ..

then
scp ./the_file me@host_to:~/

and worked fine